# How can we implement incoming call in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to make a fake incoming call in windows phone 8. As we can compose a call can i do the same with incoming call.
For Making a call i am using following code:

```
PhoneCallTask phoneCallTask = new PhoneCallTask();
phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "8920383839";
phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Gage";
phoneCallTask.Show();
```

Comment: Do you need to simulate an actual call for your app? Or is it for testing purposes what happens to your app when you are getting called?

Comment: Yeaa @GeraldVersluis I want to simulate an actual call(incoming) in my App. Assume there wil be a button when user will click on that a page will be showing with the incoming call from the entered number.

Comment: I don't think you can actually do that. The only thing you could do is to build a screen that looks a lot like the Windows Phone incoming call screen, mimic it's behaviour and show that instead.

Comment: Okay Got It.. Thanku So Much @GeraldVersluis :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly make a phone call (real & fake) in Windows Phone.However , if your app has **ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER** capability , you can show a popup for user to call the number you provided in your code.

In addition , there's no way to catch incoming calls.It's not permitted via Windows Phone API's.

You can create a fresh XAML page that strecthes to the screen and put some XAML controls inside it to get a fake incoming call screen , play a ringtone and achieve what you want.However , I doubt that application will go through Store :)